# How to get the value of a tag with multiple similar siblings?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, parent-child

I am using XML, BeuatifulSoup, and Python to parse data. In this specific XML document, there are multiple children that have different tag names with different values, but all have the same child name.

I have attached an image of the directory and how the layout exists. I am trying to get the value for Occupation, MIBCarrierCode, MIBTestIndicator, and so on.

[Schema of Parent, Child and Children directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNybo.png)

```
with open("arc45.xml", 'r') as file:
data = file.read()

Bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

Occupation = Bs_data.find_all("Name")
print(Occupation)
```

Output:

```
[-Name-Occupation-/Name-, -Name-CarrierCode-/Name-, -Name-TestIndicator-/Name-, -Name-LineOfBusinessCode-/Name-]
```

This only gives me the first tag "Name" but I need to grab the value and have it equal to an Occupation variable.

If I say value I receive this output:

```
Occupation = Bs_data.find_all("Value")
    print(Occupation)
```

Output:

```
[-Value-Unknown-/Value-, -Value-111-/Value-, -Value-0-/Value-, -Value-1-/Value-]
```

I need to grab the value when the tag is Occupation or CarrierCode, and so on.

This is an example of the layout of the XML file.

```
-AdditonalAttributes- -Attribute- -Name- Occupation -Name- -Value- Unknown -Value- / -Attribute- -Attribute- -Name- CarrierCode -Name- -Value- 656 -Value-
```

- All - symbols should be replaced with >, for the sake of showing the XML format without the symbols disappearing.

Just not quite sure how to parse this information.

Comment: Please show us actual XML markup as plain text (not images). Provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you post code that we can run, edit / tweak, and run again, the quality of assistance you might potentially receive will be far higher. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have made corrections, please let me know if this lives up to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It comes closer to a mre and for first time. - Do not stop improving, check also formatting your code blocks https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code - You are on a good way.

Comment: Consider edit your post.  Maybe with DATA users can help you faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `select()` or `find_all()` of the `<Attribute>` and check its `<Name>` against a *whitelist* or what ever you need to, while iterating the `ResultSet`:

```
for a in soup.select('Attribute'):
    if a.Name.get_text(strip=True) in ['Occupation','CarrierCode']:
        print(a.Value.get_text(strip=True))
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml='''
<AdditonalAttributes>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> Occupation </Name> 
        <Value> Unknown </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> CarrierCode </Name>
        <Value> 656 </Value>
    </Attribute>
<AdditonalAttributes>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

for a in soup.select('Attribute'):
    if a.Name.get_text(strip=True) in ['Occupation','CarrierCode']:
        print(a.Value.get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Output

```
Unknown
656
```

Comment: This is great, now if I wanted to assign each individual output to an individual variable. i.e. Output for Occupation = Unkown, CarrierCode = 656, and son on.

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - So lets practice writing good questions. Challenge accepted?

Comment: Made a new question. I will be better at etiquette here @hedgehog